# Starting Tomcat 7 from command line (Windows)

Tags: java, batch-file, tomcat, server

I'm wondering if there is a way to start `Tomcat7` server from the cmd line? 
I researched this and all signs seem to be pointing to running a `startup.bat/shutdown.bat` file that should be present in the bin folder of my `Tomcat` directory.

However, my bin folder doesn't contain these files.
It only contains:

```
- bootstrap.jar
- Tomcat7
- Tomcat7w
- tomcat-juli.jar
```

I did a bit more searching for these .bat files and stumbled across shortcuts called '`Configure Tomcat`' and '`Modify Tomcat`'. The 'Configure Tomcat' just gives you an option to start/stop the server by clicking a button and the 'Monitor Tomcat' didn't appear to do anything.

Is this normal? Or did something go wrong with my download? 
I feel like there should definitely be a way to start the server in the cmd line.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I uninstalled and reinstalled Tomcat7 and there were still no startup/shutdown.bat files present but however now I can start and stop the server from the system tray beside the clock. Hopefully this will help me..

Comment: nothing in the `c:\Oracle\Middleware\opdq\server\tomcat\bin`?

Comment: `sc start tomcat` should work

Comment: @RachelSolomon, looks like your Ring at instance isn't complete... `startup.bat`, `shutdown.bat` are basics that come with any Ring at instance extract.

Comment: Thanks all for responding.. 
@AnnaJeanine nope, nothing there either..

Comment: @Jens any specific directory  to be in for that?

Comment: Have you tried locating the file in any other way? Through the command line or windows search?

Comment: @N00bPr0grammer  I had a feeling that it wasn't complete.. Might have to download it again and reinstall it.

Comment: @RachelSolomon No. But the Name of the Service must match with the Name in the Windows services

Comment: @AnnaJeanine I have, only found startup/shutdown cmds for Tomcat5 (thought they were for Tomcat 7 originally but then later realised..)

Comment: Hmm. I'd suggest you could re-install the TomCat. I tried to install it too a year ago and it was a real pain in the ass. I'd suggest you could you something like Vagrant and Virtual Box to install the Tomcat on easy linux

Comment: @RachelSolomonHave you seen this: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html

Comment: @AnnaJeanine thanks for your advice :) I will try re-install it again and hopefully it'll work. Don't suppose anyone has any idea what these 'Configure Tomcat' and 'Monitor Tomcat' shortcuts are for?

Comment: @RachelSolomon, that's the way to go right now for you...

Comment: @Jens I remember looking at that a while ago but I will read it again just in case. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @RachelSolomon You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

The Tomcat EXE/installer package for some reason does not include the startup scripts found in the `bin/` directory. Instead, grab the ZIP distribution and copy the files from the `bin/` directory into your existing installation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's so helpful. I reinstalled my Tomcat and it still didnt include the startup scripts so I was confused once again! I will look into the zip distribution.